# Mongodb : error while loading shared libraries: libboost_thread.so.1.54.0: > cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, linux, mongodb, qt

I am trying to connect MongoDb with Qt c++. When I build it there is no error, just information like;

> :-1: warning: libboost_system.so.1.54.0, needed by
>   /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.so, may conflict with
>   libboost_system.so.5

However when I tried to Run it says:

> error while loading shared libraries: libboost_thread.so.1.54.0:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Here is my small code sample which everything looks fine.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include <mongo/client/dbclient.h>


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    try
    {
        mongo::DBClientConnection c;
        c.connect("localhost");

        qDebug() << "Connected to Mongo";
    }
    catch (mongo::DBException &e)
    {
        qDebug() << "Cannot, Error : " << e.what();
    }

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Could you please help me why I am getting this error and how to fix it ?

**EDIT :**

Here is also my .pro file ;

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = mongodbtest
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/lib/

LIBS += -pthread \
    -lmongoclient \
    -lboost_thread \
    -lboost_system \
    -lboost_regex
```

and I see that I already have libboost_thread.so.1.54.0

> [mg@mg-CentOS mg]$ locate libboost_thread.so.1.54.0
>   /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.54.0

Comment: It seems that you have 2 boost_threads/systems library in your path and that the wrong one is picked. Can you check?

Comment: Yes, you are right for my other job I need other boost_thread too. Question is how to define correct one for that purpose.. `INCLUDE_PATH` didnt solve my problem too.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have twice the boost libraries in your path, and both seem to be in `/usr/local/lib` (not good).

Easiest solution is to use only one set of boost libraries if you can.

Else, the best setup would be achieved by installing boost in a specific (not global) location and linked to it (I'm not really familiar with qmake):

```
INCLUDEPATH  += /path/to/boost/boost_1_54_0/include
QMAKE_LIBDIR += /path/to/boost/boost_1_54_0/lib
LIBS         += -libboost_system.so.1.54.0  # relative link (preferred)
LIBS         += /path/to/boost/boost_1_54_0/lib/libboost_thread.1.54.0.so  # hard link
...
```

Comment: Thank you for help, I solved via environment variable settings including in build step